# Variables not being sent to server when using POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wamp

The user runs a page on their computer with the following `JavaScript`/`Ajax`:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "ProcessRequest.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(encodeURIComponent("fname=Mr.&lname=tester"));
```

The server side script ProcessRequest.php can't seem to access the variables.
For example
`$_POST['fname']` 
gives the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: fname

What am I doing wrong? I'm running this using WAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encoding too much. What you need is something like this:

```
xmlhttp.send("fname=" + encodeURIComponent("Mr.") + "&lname=" + encodeURIComponent("tester"));
```

Of course you can use a function to make that more DRY.